# How can I list the numbers between 0 and n, where the sum of number and its positive divisors will make a perfect square?

Tags: c

I'm supposed to take n as an input from user and list some numbers between 0 and n with specific condition.

The condition is this: The sum of the number and all of its divisors should provide a perfect square. (for example: suppose that a's divisors are b and c. a + b + c should be a perfect square)

Plus, as an output, I must list:

The number - All of its divisors by ascending order - The sum of divisors
(a b c b+c)

As a whole example, if 'n' is 50, then it should print (as the 33 is the only number providing that condition that's smaller than 50):
33 1 3 11 33 48

So far, I have written a function that checks if a number is a perfect square or not. Also, I have also tried to write a function that can complete all of this but came up short. So, by looking at the code, can you tell me where have I gone wrong, and what should I do instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int squareRoot(int n)
{
    int a= 0;

    for(; a*a <=n; a= a+1 )
        ;

    return a-1;
}

int IsPerfectSquare(int num)
{
    int b;

    b = squareRoot(num);

    if (b*b == num)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n0, n1, n2, n3, sum, n4, n5;

    scanf("%d", &n0);

    for(n1 = 0 ; n1<n0; n1++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(n2 = n1 ; n2 <= n1 && n2 >0 ;n2--)
        {
          if (n1%n2 == 0) 
          {
            n3 = n1/n2;
            sum = sum + n3;
            n4 = sum + n1;
            n5 = IsPerfectSquare(n4);
            if (n5 == 1)
            {   
             printf("%d %d %d", n1, n3, sum);
            }
          }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Does 1 count as a divisor?  It probably should.  In general, numbers can have many more than 2 divisors — for example, 18 has divisors 1, 2, 3, 6, 9 (and 18), so the sum is 39, and it doesn't qualify for printing.  But you're going to need an array to store divisors.  And more loops — to determine divisors and to print them.  You'll also need to print a newline at the end of the output for each relevant number.

Comment: Also, don't you get a divide by zero error on `if (n1 % n2 == 0)` on the first iteration when `n1` is zero — or on the line `n3 = n1 / n2;`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe it's n2 that can not be zero, which I prevented it from being zero with 'n2 <= n1 && n2 >0' in the loop condition.

Comment: Oh — hmmm; that's a weird way of writing the condition. When would `n2` be greater than `n1`?  Does that loop ever execute? Certainly not on the iteration where `n1 == 0`, but I'm not clear why you want such a convoluted condition when it would be more sensible to start with `n1 = 1` in the outer loop, wouldn't it?  If you don't want the inner loop to execute on the first value of the outer loop, change the first value of the outer loop.  Note that you're testing for `IsPerfectSquare()` far too soon and too often.  It should be tested outside the inner loop (but inside the outer loop).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did that but nothing changed. For some insight, the n1 values that are printed are.```3 6 8 15 21 22 22 24 30 33 35 45 46 48 48 48``` when it should be just 33. What causes that?

Comment: *"suppose that a's divisors are b and c. a + b + c should be a perfect square)"* and the example *"33 1 3 11 33"* are contradictory. If a is 33, then b is 1, c is 3, and d is 11. But a + b + c + d is not a perfect square.

Comment: @user3386109 The sum of 33's divisors, which are 1, 3, 11 and 33 is 48, which equals 81 if you sum it with 33 itself. I guess I could not express that well in the question.

Comment: I guess my question is, "did you make up the example with 33, or was that example given to you as part of the problem statement?"

Comment: @user3386109 It was given as a part of the problem statement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler n2 would never be greater than n1 as it's in the loop conditions. I tried to cut ```n5 = IsPerfectSquare(n4);
            if (n5 == 1)
            {   
             printf("%d %d %d", n1, n3, sum); ``` from its initial position and place it between the loops, but this time I could get no output.

Comment: You can't do the job properly without an array — trying to work with a number like 120 (factors 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120) with variables `n1`, `n2`, etc doesn't make any sense whatsoever.    Or, if you do work it without an array, you have to first determine the sum of the factors (plus the number you first thought of — the 33 example is interesting; I'd not have guessed that you need to count 33 twice!) and then check the condition, and then, to print all the factors in ascending order, you have to determine them all over again.  I suppose that _is_ doable.

Comment: And I can see that `n2` would never be greater than `n1` because you set it to the value of `n1` and then decrease it, so the test for `n2 <= n1` is pointless — not actually 'wrong',  but totally unnecessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the ```sum = sum + n3;``` part in the loop does determine the sum of the factors and ```n4 = sum + n1;``` does determine the number which will be checked if it's perfect square or not. I can print all the factors in ascending order as well but I can only do them seperately. I do not know how to make them work in harmony properly without an array. (Array is something we've learned very recently so I refrain from using that)

Comment: Yes, it does.  But you're testing before you know all the factors, so you can get wrong answers.  The `IsPerfectSquare()` test cannot be correctly performed before the inner loop has determined all of the factors. You currently test as each factor is found — that means you get different answers depending on whether you factor counting down or counting up, in general, at least. And then the code to print all the factors has to determine all the factors again. Normally, you'd use an array to save that recalculation. But you can recalculate if you prefer — just make sure you use the right order.

Comment: @GarlanTheGallant I agree with Jonathan that the best way to do this is with an array. I would use an array size of 100, since that's plenty big for what you're doing. Then I would start by writing a function that takes a number and an array. The function should fill the array with the divisors of that number, and return the number of divisors. Given that you've recently studied arrays, and this problem is best solved with an array, I expect that you're supposed to use an array.

Comment: @user3386109 I would normally agree with you but this assignment was given before we learned what an array is. By the way, it seems that it's going to work. Will definitely update if it does.

Comment: @GarlanTheGallant Fair enough, then it's plan B. Write a loop that computes the sum of the divisors. ***After*** the loop, add the number to the sum, and check if the result is a perfect square. If it is a perfect square, then a second loop should print the divisors

Comment: There are far more such numbers than I'd've expected.  There are 98 of them less than 100,000; the largest is `99684 1 2 3 4 6 9 12 13 18 26 27 36 39 52 54 71 78 108 117 142 156 213 234 284 351 426 468 639 702 852 923 1278 1404 1846 1917 2556 2769 3692 3834 5538 7668 8307 11076 16614 24921 33228 49842 99684 282240`.  (Factoring: `99684: (2^2).(3^3).13.71)`.) That took a bit over 6 seconds on a Mac.  Up to a million takes a lot longer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have nearly completed it. It successfully prints out 33 from 50, prints out n1 and sum, but n3 only prints out the number you get when it is divided by 1. Basically with the input 50, it prints out ''33 33 48'' instead of ''33 1 3 11 33 48''. I suppose I should do another loop for that, but how?

Comment: Except that you need to count up rather than down, roughly the way you determined whether the `n2` was a factor or not — `for (int n2 = 1; n2 <= n1; n2++) { if (n1 % n2 == 0) printf(" %d", n2); }`?

Comment: Going up to 1,000,000 took about 10.5 minutes; there were 351 matching numbers, the largest requiring the output `996769 1 71 101 139 7171 9869 14039 996769 1028160`.  (Factoring: `996769:    71.101.139`.)  That's a fairly good demonstration of quadratic behaviour — 10 times as many input values took 100 times as long to process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It worked out in the end, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the guidelines stated in the comments, and avoiding arrays by doing the analysis of factors twice, I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static int squareRoot(int n)
{
    int a;

    for (a = 0; a * a <= n; a++)
        ;

    return a - 1;
}

static bool IsPerfectSquare(int num)
{
    int b;

    b = squareRoot(num);

    if (b * b == num)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n0;

    if (scanf("%d", &n0) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read an integer\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int n1 = 1; n1 < n0; n1++)
    {
        int sum = n1 + 1;
        for (int n2 = 2; n2 <= n1 / 2; n2++)
        {
            if (n1 % n2 == 0)
                sum += n2;
        }
        if (IsPerfectSquare(sum + n1))
        {
            printf("%d 1", n1);
            for (int n2 = 2; n2 <= n1 / 2; n2++)
            {
                if (n1 % n2 == 0)
                    printf(" %d", n2);
            }
            printf(" %d %d\n", n1, sum);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run (with a Bash [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) providing the input and a custom (home-brew) timing command (`-m` for milliseconds), I got the output:

```
$ timecmd -m -- fs17 <<< '1000' 
2019-10-23 00:07:43.032 [PID 9520] fs17
33 1 3 11 33 48
90 1 2 3 5 6 9 10 15 18 30 45 90 234
385 1 5 7 11 35 55 77 385 576
420 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 12 14 15 20 21 28 30 35 42 60 70 84 105 140 210 420 1344
649 1 11 59 649 720
900 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10 12 15 18 20 25 30 36 45 50 60 75 90 100 150 180 225 300 450 900 2821
2019-10-23 00:07:43.046 [PID 9520; status 0x0000]  -  0.013s
$
```

As noted in the comments, it takes a lot longer to reach 1,000,000.